# Pass C# Dictionary<string, string> to PHP Nusoap

Tags: c#, php, nusoap

I have a PHP web service running using NuSoap. I have a PHP function that executes a stored procedure on a MSSQL server. I am trying to understand how I can pass a C# Dictionary to the webservice so that it can be consumed like an associative array by PHP.

Assume the project is far enough along where I am locked into NuSoap and C#. I'm open to changing the PHP function though and passing my C# params in a different way if this method isn't possible.

The PHP function was written to use an associative array like so:

```
function runReport($input) {

global $cwlink;

$query = "EXEC localhost.dbo.".$input['report'];

$first = true;
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    if($first) {
        $first = false;
        continue;
    }

    $query .= " @".$key." = '".$value."',";
}

$query = substr($query, 0, -1);

$results = mssql_query($query, $cwlink);
$rows = mssql_fetch_array($results);

$return = array();

do {
    do {
        $return[] = $rows;
    }while($rows = mssql_fetch_array($results));
}while(mssql_next_result($results));

return $return; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I ended up modifying my input array to expect a standard array and separated out my report name and my input parameters as two separate inputs.

```
function runReport($reportName, $input)
{
    global $cwlink;

    $query = "EXEC localhost.dbo.".$reportName;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($input); $i = $i + 2) {
        $query .= " @".$input[$i]." = '".$input[$i + 1]."',";
    }

    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);

    $results = mssql_query($query, $cwlink);
    $rows = mssql_fetch_array($results);

    $return = array();

    do {
        do {
            $return[] = $rows;
        }while($rows = mssql_fetch_array($results));
    }while(mssql_next_result($results));

    return $return;
}
```